# Performance Analysis of Private Ethereum Blockchain using Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, poa

I have built a private blockchain network using goEthereum with PoA consensus model using Clique. The nodes are live and connected. I want to measure its performance(Throughput, latency..), using  Prometheus and Grafana, and also compare it with other blockchain models. How do I implement it?

ps: I am new to the blockchain community and blockchain development. I'm not sure if its the right kind of questions to post here but, I couldn't find any solution elsewhere. so trying my luck here. Please help!